# Header and source class file not working

Tags: c++, class, header, g++

I got a basic program running but when I try to create a header and class file I have no success. I was wondering if someone could look at my code and see where I am going wrong. I am doing this with a text editor on Linux and using G++ for compiling.

down.h

```
#ifndef down_h
#define down_h

#include <string>

class down{
//function of web page retreival
private:
void write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
}

//webpage retrieval
public:
down();
std::string getString(const char *url){
}
};

#endif
```

down.cpp

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "down.h"
using namespace std;

//function of web page retreival
size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
std::ostringstream *stream = (std::ostringstream*)userdata;
size_t count = size * nmemb;
stream->write(ptr, count);
return count;
}

//webpage retrieval
std::string getString(const char *url){
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
std::ostringstream stream;
CURLcode res;
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "bbb.txt";
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &stream);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
fclose(fp);
}
return stream.str();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "down.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    const char *url = "www.google.com";
    std::cout << getString("www.google.com");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't give your functions a empty body in the header file.

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code. I don't care what indentation scheme you use, but do use one.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code:

`void write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
}`

in the header *down.h* file, you are implementing the function, that does nothing, making it an [inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y.aspx) useless method. You do it again in *down.cpp*, but you cannot do it.

Your code should look like this in the *down.h* header file:

```
void write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

In your *down.cpp*, on the other hand, you have a lot of errors: when you want to implement a method in the *cpp* source file, you have specifically to say that that method is part of the class *down* (which should be written capitalised *Down*), using the [scope operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator):

```
size_t down::write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    std::ostringstream *stream = (std::ostringstream*)userdata;
    size_t count = size * nmemb;
    stream->write(ptr, count);
    return count;
}
```

The same can be said for your `getString` method. You have also other errors, for example, in the header file you are declaring a default constructor, but you are not implementing it.

I really recommend you to read a book or watch some other [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_object_oriented.htm) on OOP for C++, because it really seems you haven't done it. You are also using too many features of C/C++ (pointers) in dangerous way...